# Enforcing a polymorphic type to have an attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, polymorphic-associations

I have a standard polymorphic relation set up like:

```
#Foo
has_many: bar, as: foobar

#Qux
has_many: bar, as: foobar

#Bar
belongs_to :foobar, polymorphic: true
```

I want to be able to enforce a model that `has_many: bar, as: foobar` to have certain attributes for example a `name`, so I can do something like:

```
bar.foobar.name
```

and know that it doesn't matter which model foobar is at that moment. (Since all foobars have a name attribute)

Is there a way to do this or do I have to test for it with `responds_to?` everytime I want to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide defaults by creating a base class that `Foo` and `Qux` extend. Instead of

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bar, as: foobar
end

class Qux < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bar, as: foobar
end
```

you could do something like

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bar, as: foobar
end

class Foo < Foobar; end

class Qux < Foobar; end
```

You could then create a default accessor method for the attributes you want to be consistent for those classes extending `Foobar`.

```
class Foobar < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many: bar, as: foobar

  def name
    "some default name"
  end
end

class Foo < Foobar
  def name
    "some overloaded name for Foo"
  end
end

class Qux < Foobar; end
```

You can overload `name` as shown above in `Foo`, or omit it as shown in `Qux`. Regardless, a `name` attribute will be available, even if it's only the default from `Foobar`.

```
foo = Foo.new
puts foo.name  # "some overloaded name for Foo"

qux = Qux.new
puts qux.name # "some default name"
```

If you're looking to create more of a contract through an interface or abstract class as is common in other languages, Ruby doesn't support either. You can however use a mixin that you'd include in `Foo` and `Qux` to throw an Exception if `name` is not defined. **[Read an example of this sort of implementation here](http://metabates.com/2011/02/07/building-interfaces-and-abstract-classes-in-ruby/)**.

**Note** on the chance these models are supposed to have an associated `name` column in the table, you will likely want to incorporate `read_attribute(:name)` somewhere in your overloaded `name` method. **[See the docs on `read_attribute`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeMethods/Read/read_attribute)**

Comment: I kinda figured I could do something along those lines, thanks.